# How to push element with kay and value in array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am iterating through an array of arrays that contains sales data returning from a MySQL query:

```
$result = mysql_query("select salespersonId,grossProfit FROM sales");
foreach ($result as $line) {
   $salespersonId = $line['salespersonId'];
   $grossProfit = $line['grossProfit'];
}
```

I want to push the line into separate arrays per salespersonId (so that the 10 lines belonging to salespersonId 1 are in one array, and the 10 lines belonging to salespersonId 2 are in a different array) but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  I've tried
things like:

`array_push(${'data'.$salespersonId},$line);` to no avail.  I feel like I might need an associative array of arrays, but you can't array_push into associative arrays.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can push value in array like `$array['key'] = 'value'` in associative array.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select salespersonId,grossProfit FROM sales");
$arr = [];
foreach ($result as $line) {
   if (empty($line['salespersonId'])) {
       continue;
   }
   $arr[$line['salespersonId']][] = $line;
}
print_r($arr);
```